# Java: Calling method from threads one after another

Tags: java, multithreading

I have class Server and subclass ClientThread. ClientThread has methods receive() and broadcast(String[] msg) used to receive and send messages from/to clients connected to server.

Scheme:

```
public class Server extends Thread {
    private ArrayList<ClientThread> clientThreads;
    class ClientThread extends Thread {
        public void broadcast(String[] msg) {...}
        public void receive() {
            ...
            if (msg.equals("CHANGED")) {
                resumeOthers();
        }

        public void suspendOthers() {
            for (ClientThread c: clientThreads)
                 if (c!=this)
                     try {
                         c.wait();
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        public void resumeOthers() {
            for (ClientThread c: clientThreads)
            if (c!=this)
                c.notify();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        ...
        cmd = new String[1];
        cmd[0] = "PROMPTCHANGE";
        for (ClientThread currPlayer: clientThreads) {
            currPlayer.broadcast(cmd);
            currPlayer.suspendOthers();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to make this ClientThreads work one after another, like this:

```
1. ClientThread number 1 is calling method broadcast.
Now any other ClientThread existing is freezed
(they are stored in ArrayList on Server)

2. Client (another class) replies with a message that is being caught by receive()
Now this thread is freezed, and the next one starts running
```

Unfortunately, my approach doesn't work.
Could somebody explain me in details how to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: No DEFINITELY this is not duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yes, there should have been equals method used or to be more specific: msg.startsWith("CHANGED"). This is just a scheme, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by calling Object.wait(), you are are suspending the CALLING thread, not the thread that this object happens to be.

so in effect, you are doing a loop that blocks the calling thread N times, definitely not what you intended.

in order to pause a thread, you need to have IT wait on an objet, or have it block entering a synchronized block (or use Thread.sleep(), but usually its not a good solution).
in other words, the client threads need to call wait, not the calling thread.

One addition:
it seems you are new to Java threading and synchronization, I strongly suggest that you read about it before attempting this.

Google around for some docs on the subject.
here is something to get you started:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Problem solved with tutorial you have sent and your suggestions, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how the sequence of execution works.
Anyway, as already said by previous answers, calling `x.wait()` on a `Object` makes the **current** thread block on object x. Moreover, in order to call `wait()` and `notify()`, you first have to synchronize on that object, AND, when you call `wait()`, you should do it in a loop, checking for an external condition, because [spurious wakeups](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html#spuriouswakeups) can happen.

So, the correct pattern should be something like:

```
void waitForCondition() {
  synchronized (lockObject) {
    while (!condition) {
      lockObject.wait();
    }
  }
}

void setCondition() {
  synchronized (lockObject) {
    condition = true;
    lockObject.notify(); //or .notifyAll()
  }
}
```

If you want to make the threads run one after another, try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html